# Spring Integration FileAggregator not invoked when the the same file is placed for reprocessing

Tags: java, spring-integration

In the below flow, the file split, aggregation works perfectly fine with new (different) files. When a processed file is placed again and picked by the `Poller`, it goes into the `FileSplitterSpec()` but never reaches the `FileAggregator`.

Are there any markers placed on the processed file, that it is failing to reach the aggregator the next time?

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(txnChannel())
                        .split(fileSplitterSpec())
                        .filter(payload -> !(payload instanceof FileMarker), e -> e.discardChannel("aggregatorChannel"))
                        .<String> filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank, e -> e.discardChannel("aggregatorChannel"))
                        .transform(transformer, "transform")
                        .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                            headers.get("indHeader", DTO.class).getTxn().add(payload);
                            return payload;
                        })
                        .channel("aggregatorChannel")
                        .aggregate(new FileAggregator())


@Bean
public FileSplitterSpec fileSplitterSpec() {

    return Files.splitter()
                .markers()
                .firstLineAsHeader("someHeader");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the correlation key for group aggregation is based on the file name. You need to use different file name or consider to configure an aggregator for `expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)`. The `new FileAggregator()` should go to the `processor()` option of the aggregator spec.

Comment: Thanq, solved the problem !!